# width of (\alph*) labels

Tags: spacing, labels, enumitem, microtype

I made a list using `enumitem` and

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
...
\end{enumerate}
```

The resulting labels are, to me, annoyingly uneven.  Notice that (b) is much wider than (c) in the image below.  Would it be possible to get the label to insert padding to get the text generated for each label to be equally wide?  This sounds like a `microtype` kind of job.  As a work around I could use a monospaced font for the labels but that's less elegant.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pre-define a length, say, `\mylength`, and then use that to make a box of constant width with `\hbox to\mylength{<stuff>}`. You can:

- center-align with `label=(\hbox to\mywidth{\hss\alph*\hss})`
- right-align with `label=(\hbox to\mywidth{\hss\alph*})`
- and left-align with `label=(\hbox to\mywidth{\alph*\hss})`

or, with a more LaTeX-*y* syntax: `label={(\makebox[\mywidth][<align>]{\alph*})}` where `<align>` is either `c`, `r`, or `l`.

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\newdimen\mywidth
\sbox0{m}%
\setlength\mywidth{\wd0}%

\begin{enumerate}[label={(\makebox[\mywidth][c]{\alph*})}]
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
  \item 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Much better than it was, thanks!  I used `\sbox{0}{b}`.  Only a real neat-freak would complain now ;-)

Comment: or even `\makebox[\mywidth]{\alph*}` so it looks like latex:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Apparently `enumitem` doesn't like LaTeX. That syntax breaks for some reason...

Comment: Don't forget the braces `\begin{enumerate}[label={(\makebox[\mywidth]{\alph*})}]` otherwise the `[` and `]` confuse the argument parser.

Comment: @moewe Oh, stupid me :/ Thanks :)

Comment: I only know that because I tried `\makebox[...]` myself and it failed.

Comment: @moewe testing code? what sort of advice is that? :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/commit/4ece391554edb67c1b999ebb59395ee70d93d1ea ;-)

Comment: @moewe sorry I misread your comment. braces around the whole thing work because of low level tex delimited argument semantics , braces around the =... bit of a key value work because keyval ensures that they do, so you can put = and , into values. Which is "clearer" here depends on your point of view